# Why doesnt work a backslash in front of a reference

Tags: junit, escaping, velocity, backslash

I wrote a simple junit test. I want to test if I can write a java escaped backslash in front of a reference. This test fails and I dont know why.

Error Message: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[\London]> but was:<[$branch]>

```java
public class VelocityBackslashTest {
    @Test
    public void testVelocityBackslash() {
        String inString = "\\$branch";

        Velocity.init();
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("branch", "London");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "test_1", inString);

        assertEquals("\\London", writer.toString());
    }

}
```

If I do the same test but reading the template from a file. The result is positiv.

```java
public class VelocityBackslashFileTest {

    @Test
    public void testVelocityBackslash() {

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("resource.loader", "classpath");
        p.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",
                ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        Velocity.init(p);
        Template template =
                Velocity.getTemplate("velocity/test_template.vm");

        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("branch", "London");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(context, writer);

        assertEquals("\\London", writer.toString());
    }
}
```

test_template.vm:

\\$branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of `java.lang.String`'s use of `\` as an escape character.

When you write

```
String inString = "\\$branch";
```

Java interprets the String literal `\\` as an escaped backslash, so what is actually getting passed to Velocity is a single `\` followed by `$branch`.

Velocity also uses `\` as the escape character, so it interprets its input (`\$branch`) as a directive to escape the `$` symbol. In other words, don't use it as Velocity markup simply print the literal `$`.  Once this has happened then of course there is no attempt to resolve `branch` as a reference hence it is output as a literal.

To print `\\` in front of a resolved Velocity reference, the Java String would need to pass 2 `\` characters to Velocity, which would be done like this:

```
String inString = "\\\\$branch";
```